# ¿Como le envio un xml a un webservice rest de content-type=application/xml?

Tags: c#, xml, webservice, rest

Quisiera saber el como puedo mandar mi xml ya estructurado a un webservice al que no tengo acceso de administrador pero si acceso de lectura y escritura.

Código de c# para enviar xml:

```
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("https:xxxxxxxxxx") as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = "POST";
 request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("rest.api", "R3ST.4P1");
            request.ContentType = "application/xml";
            request.Accept = "application/xml";
            Encoding e = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml("<request><entry><name>Nombre</name><quantity>12</quantity><u_clase_de_coste>sysid</u_clase_de_coste><u_horas>1.5</u_horas><u_importe_moneda_origen>234432.12</u_importe_moneda_origen><unit_cost>10.12</unit_cost></entry></request>");
            string rawXml = doc.OuterXml;
            string requestText = rawXml;
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, e);
            requestWriter.Write(requestText);
            requestWriter.Close();
            HttpWebResponse response;
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Es un webservice de tipo Rest y esta dado por la plataforma de ServiceNow

Con esta linea de la siguiente forma:

```
request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("USER", "PASS", "Domain");
```

Me sale el error de 401 no autorizado

Si la pongo de la siguiente forma:

```
request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("USER", "PASS");
```

Me dice el error 403 que indica  `Error en el servidor remoto: (403) Prohibido.`

El problema no es la autenticación ya que si entro por medio del navegador si ingresa.

El error sale en la siguiente linea:

```
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Cuando llega a la siguiente linea:

```
 Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
```

me sale el siguiente error:

```
Length = '((System.Net.ConnectStream)requestStream).Length' threw an exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException'
```

Igual cuando pasa sobre la linea siguiente:

```
StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, e);
```

Comment: cuando dices webservice te refieres a WCF o a un asmx ?

Comment: has intentado realizar la misma solicitud en la aplicación postman? De ser así, podrías anexar la imagen con respuesta de éxito o error?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini un WCF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo hago algo similar
pero el ContentType lo manejo de esta manera

```
 oRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8;";
```

Y utilizo este encabezado

```
oRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentEncoding, "utf-8");
```

el resto de mi código es muy similar al tuyo

Answer (score 0):

Si es un `WCF` debes tener la url al servicio `.svc`, con esa url podrias crear la `Service Reference`, no necesitas usar el `HttpWebRequest` ni invocarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en el dialogo ingresar la url del servicio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto creara el codigo del `proxy` que instancia y puedes invocar el metodo que expone el servicio.

En la propiedad `Credentials` podrias asignar el usuario y password si es que requiere autenticacion

[How to consume WCF service in MVC](https://dotnet-helpers.com/mvc/how-to-consume-wcf-service-in-mvc/)

Comment: Creo que mandar llamar al servicio no es el problema, el OP indica que tiene problemas al enviar las credenciales

Comment: Pero si es un servicio WCF debe armar correctamente el `envelope` del xml del servicio para poder invocar al metodo, de nada sirven las credenciales si lo primero no se realiza correctamente. La unica forma de armarlo sin errores es por medio de una service reference, en donde ademas podra asignar las credenciales, porque esta la propiedad para esto